# deploying spark cluster through docker-compose in dock swarm mode

Tags: apache-spark, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I'm trying to deploy my apache spark cluster using the `docker-compose` file as defined [here](https://github.com/infsaulo/docker-spark/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) across machines working in docker swarm mode.

I'm invoking `docker stack deploy -c compose-file.yml spark_cluster` at my docker swarm manager machine to deploy my services as defined but I'm getting the following scenario when I hit `docker stack ps spark_cluster`:

```
ID            NAME                        IMAGE                           NODE           DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE               ERROR                             PORTS
iy255fvx5ub8  spark_cluster_master.1      sauloricci/docker-spark:latest  manager-swarm  Running        Running 20 seconds ago
mrr6p9dmodh5   \_ spark_cluster_master.1  sauloricci/docker-spark:latest  worker2-swarm  Shutdown       Rejected 35 seconds ago     "invalid mount config for type�"
u1daipeekanv   \_ spark_cluster_master.1  sauloricci/docker-spark:latest  worker2-swarm  Shutdown       Rejected 40 seconds ago     "invalid mount config for type�"
9yup3zxpk4ur   \_ spark_cluster_master.1  sauloricci/docker-spark:latest  worker2-swarm  Shutdown       Rejected 45 seconds ago     "invalid mount config for type�"
is4dib7wmb61   \_ spark_cluster_master.1  sauloricci/docker-spark:latest  worker1-swarm  Shutdown       Rejected 50 seconds ago     "invalid mount config for type�"
y80py4s4hny8  spark_cluster_worker.1      sauloricci/docker-spark:latest  manager-swarm  Running        Running about a minute ago
```

It seems the swarm just accepted the services running at my swarm manager node and rejected at my worker swarm nodes.

How could I manage to find the logs associated with this scenario? Where could I check the logs related with this deployment if that's the case? I'd like to know what exactly means the message in the error column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `docker stack ps <STACK> --no-trunc` to get the full text of the error message.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_ps/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .yml file doesn't contain volumes , because each servers has different local folder, Work for me